# openam dedicated instance architecture?

Tags: tomcat, openam, opensso, opends

- It is possible to install openam on a dedicated web/application server instance (apache-tomcat) and install our web applications (sso clients) on a different application server instance(s)?
- If the above is possible, so what's the better approach? having openam and the web application(s) (sso clients) on the same apache-tomcat instance or on a separates instances (1 openam instance + n web applications instance)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it possible to install OpenAM on a dedicated instance, this is strongly recommended. Co-installing other applications in the same container as OpenAM is likely to cause issues.